# is there a function that allows you to find what is not in the data frame?

Tags: r

I made a data frame filled with odd and even numbers. I know how to filter for both odds and evens. But is there a way to filter it by the complement of each? Like is there a way to filter by "not odd" or "not even."

Comment: You can just add a `!` in front of your condition, that means "not".

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Yes you're right, I will make a note of that for next time. Thanks.